# Position and fade in div on scroll & return when original position is visible

Tags: jquery

I think maybe I'm over thinking this one,  but basically I have some buttons generated on the page. These are specific to the page and generated at load. So I can't regenerate the button. What I'm trying to do is on scroll, have the button move off to the right then slide in and gradually become visible on scroll down. When the original position, higher up in the document becomes visible again I'd like to fade out the button and fade in the button in its original position. I've been trying a few different things, but I've attached my original work first followed by my newest attempt at controlling the state.

> First attempt is okay.

```
$(window).on("load mousewheel scroll",function(e){
if (!$('.home').length){    
/*
* clone and add new id
*/

    function getScrollBarWidth () {  
        var inner = document.createElement('p');  
        inner.style.width = "100%";  
        inner.style.height = "200px";  

        var outer = document.createElement('div');  
        outer.style.position = "absolute";  
        outer.style.top = "0px";  
        outer.style.left = "0px";  
        outer.style.visibility = "hidden";  
        outer.style.width = "200px";  
        outer.style.height = "150px";  
        outer.style.overflow = "hidden";  
        outer.appendChild (inner);  

        document.body.appendChild (outer);  
        var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;  
        outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';  
        var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;  
        if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;  

        document.body.removeChild (outer);  

        return (w1 - w2);  
    };  
            var scrollBarSize = getScrollBarWidth();
            var wrapRequestSide = $('#wrapRequestSide');
            var wrapRequestSideWidth = $('#wrapRequestSide').outerWidth();//button containing div width
            var wrapRequestSideHeight = $('#wrapRequestSide').outerHeight();//button containing div height
            var mainContainerW = $('#windowWidth').outerWidth();//outer page container width
            var pageTopRequestW = $('#pageTopRequest').width();//button width
            var pageTopRequestH = $('#pageTopRequest').height();//button height
            if (wrapRequestSide.length) {//if button container exists
                var get_window_top = $(document).scrollTop();
                var get_window_right =   document.body.clientWidth;  
                //window width - scrollbar viewport function
                function viewport() {
                  var e = window, a = 'inner';
                  if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
                    a = 'client';
                    e = document.documentElement || document.body;
                  }
                  return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
                }
                /**/
                var vWidth = viewport().width;//viewport width
                var bodyStart = $('#wrapper').offset().top;//body of content start position

                if (get_window_top >= bodyStart) {//if top of window i greater or = to the start of the body content/button position.
                    $(wrapRequestSide).css({
                            "position": "fixed",
                            "left": mainContainerW - (wrapRequestSideWidth - pageTopRequestW - pageTopRequestH) - scrollBarSize + "px",
                            "opacity": "0",
                            "z-index": "50",
                            "-webkit-transform": "rotate(-90deg)",
                            "-moz-transform": "rotate(-90deg)",
                            //"opacity":"1",
                            /*"padding-bottom" : "90px",
                            "font-size" : "16px"*/
                    });
                    $(window).bind('mousewheel scroll', function(event) {
                                                         // alert('bind');
                        if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {//scroll up

                        }
                        else {//scroll down

                        var get_window_topSub = $(document).scrollTop();
                        var bodyStartSub = $('#wrapper').offset().top;
                            if($(wrapRequestSide).css('opacity') >= 0 && get_window_topSub >= bodyStartSub) {
                                    increaseOpacity();
                                    function increaseOpacity () {  
                                         x = 0;
                                          scrollDist = wrapRequestSideHeight;
                                         y = 0;
                                        $(window).bind('mousewheel scroll', function(event) {
                                             op = parseFloat(wrapRequestSide.css('opacity'));   

                                             if(op >= 0 && op <=1 ){ op = parseFloat(op+0.01);/*console.log(op);*/ }
                                             //console.log(op);
                                            $(wrapRequestSide).css({
                                                    "opacity" : op,
                                                    //"left" : + cssChange() + "px"
                                                    "left": mainContainerW - (wrapRequestSideWidth - pageTopRequestW - pageTopRequestH)-cssChange() - scrollBarSize + "px"
                                            });
                                            function cssChange() {
                                            if(y < scrollDist){return y+=2.5}   
                                            }
                                        });
                                    };//end function increaseOpacity
                            }
                            else {
                                $(wrapRequestSide).removeAttr( "style" );   
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }//if get_window_top >=bodyStart end
                else {
                stop(); 
                $(wrapRequestSide).removeAttr( "style" );   
                }
    }//if nav.length
}//if !home end
});
```

> Second attempt not so pretty

```
$(window).on("load",function(e){
var setState = 0;                                          
    if (!$('.home').length){    
    $(window).on("mousewheel scroll",function(e){
    /*
    * clone and add new id
    */

        function getScrollBarWidth () {  
            var inner = document.createElement('p');  
            inner.style.width = "100%";  
            inner.style.height = "200px";  

            var outer = document.createElement('div');  
            outer.style.position = "absolute";  
            outer.style.top = "0px";  
            outer.style.left = "0px";  
            outer.style.visibility = "hidden";  
            outer.style.width = "200px";  
            outer.style.height = "150px";  
            outer.style.overflow = "hidden";  
            outer.appendChild (inner);  

            document.body.appendChild (outer);  
            var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;  
            outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';  
            var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;  
            if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;  

            document.body.removeChild (outer);  

            return (w1 - w2);  
        };  
                var scrollBarSize = getScrollBarWidth();
                var wrapRequestSide = $('#wrapRequestSide');
                var wrapRequestSideWidth = $('#wrapRequestSide').outerWidth();//button containing div width
                var wrapRequestSideHeight = $('#wrapRequestSide').outerHeight();//button containing div height
                var mainContainerW = $('#windowWidth').outerWidth();//outer page container width
                var pageTopRequestW = $('#pageTopRequest').width();//button width
                var pageTopRequestH = $('#pageTopRequest').height();//button height
                if (wrapRequestSide.length) {//if button container exists
                    var get_window_top = $(document).scrollTop();
                    var get_window_right =   document.body.clientWidth;  
                    //window width - scrollbar viewport function
                    function viewport() {
                      var e = window, a = 'inner';
                      if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
                        a = 'client';
                        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
                      }
                      return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
                    }
                    /**/
                    var vWidth = viewport().width;//viewport width
                    var bodyStart = $('#right-content').offset().top;//body of content start position

                    if (get_window_top >= bodyStart) {//if top of window i greater or = to the start of the body content/button position.
                        if(setState == 0) {
                            //alert('is 0');
                            $(wrapRequestSide).css({
                                "position": "fixed",
                                "left": mainContainerW - (wrapRequestSideWidth - pageTopRequestW - pageTopRequestH) - scrollBarSize + "px",
                                "opacity": "0",
                                "z-index": "50",
                                "-webkit-transform": "rotate(-90deg)",
                                "-moz-transform": "rotate(-90deg)",
                                //"opacity":"1",
                                /*"padding-bottom" : "90px",
                                "font-size" : "16px"*/
                        });
                            setState = 1;
                        }
                        //console.log(setState);

                            var lastScrollTop = 0;
                            $(window).scroll(function(event){
                               var st = $(this).scrollTop();
                               if (st > lastScrollTop){
                                   // downscroll code
                                    var get_window_topSub = $(document).scrollTop();
                                    var bodyStartSub = $('#wrapper').offset().top;
                                    if($(wrapRequestSide).css('opacity') >= 0) {
                                            increaseOpacity();
                                            function increaseOpacity () {  
                                                 x = 0;
                                                  scrollDist = wrapRequestSideHeight;
                                                 y = 0;
                                                $(window).bind('mousewheel scroll', function(event) {
                                                     op = parseFloat(wrapRequestSide.css('opacity'));   

                                                     if(op >= 0 && op <=1 ){ op = parseFloat(op+0.01);/*console.log(op);*/ }
                                                     //console.log(op);
                                                    $(wrapRequestSide).css({
                                                            "opacity" : op,
                                                            //"left" : + cssChange() + "px"
                                                            "left": mainContainerW - (wrapRequestSideWidth - pageTopRequestW - pageTopRequestH)-cssChange() - scrollBarSize + "px"
                                                    });
                                                    function cssChange() {
                                                    if(y < scrollDist){return y+=2.5}   
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            };//end function increaseOpacity
                                    }
                                    /*else {
                                        $(wrapRequestSide).removeAttr( "style" );   
                                    }*/
                                    /*
                                    * scroll down end
                                                        */
                               } else {
                                  // upscroll code
                                    var get_window_topSub = $(document).scrollTop();
                                    var bodyStartSub = $('#wrapper').offset().top;
                                    if($(wrapRequestSide).css('opacity') >= 0) {
                                            increaseOpacity();
                                            function increaseOpacity () {  
                                                 x = 0;
                                                  scrollDist = wrapRequestSideHeight;
                                                 y = 0;
                                                $(window).bind('mousewheel scroll', function(event) {
                                                     op = parseFloat(wrapRequestSide.css('opacity'));   

                                                     if(op >= 0 && op <=1 ){ op = parseFloat(op+0.01);/*console.log(op);*/ }
                                                     //console.log(op);
                                                    $(wrapRequestSide).css({
                                                            "opacity" : op,
                                                            //"left" : + cssChange() + "px"
                                                            "left": mainContainerW - (wrapRequestSideWidth - pageTopRequestW - pageTopRequestH)-cssChange() - scrollBarSize + "px"
                                                    });
                                                    function cssChange() {
                                                    if(y < scrollDist){return y+=2.5}   
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            };//end function increaseOpacity
                                    }
                                    /*else {
                                        $(wrapRequestSide).removeAttr( "style" );   
                                    }*/
                                    /*
                                    * upscroll end
                                                        */
                               }
                               lastScrollTop = st;
                            });                              // alert('bind');

                    }//if get_window_top >=bodyStart end
                    else {
                    setState = 0;
                    //console.log(setState);
                    $(wrapRequestSide).animate({"left":"","position":"","transform":""}, "slow");
                    }
        }//if nav.length
    });//scroll
    }//if !home end
});
```

Comment: 1st, what if we scroll with the keyboard ? 2nd, You may be right, it looks waaaaaaay too much complicated for such a simple thing. Why dont you just bind scrolltop property to position and oppacity of your buttons ?

Comment: @TCHdvlp Thanks! I thought I was just imagining that. Can you explain your bind solution a bit more?

Comment: Let say you have scrolled to the middle of your page. It is quite simple to know that you are at 50% of the page (scrollTop, offset, etc... while help you). Now, you just have to store it in a variable, say `scrollPercent`. At least, apply this percentage to the oppacity and left or right position of your buttons thanks to `.css()`.

Comment: @TCHdvlp Thanks for that info. Do you have an example of this in action? My strong point is PHP not jquery/javascript.

Comment: Height of the document : http://api.jquery.com/height/   How far did you scrolled : http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/  change css property : https://api.jquery.com/css/  like `.css( "opacity", opacity )  .css( "left", left )  .css( "right", right )

Comment: I understand those, maybe I'm just not understanding your approach as it applies tow hat I'm doing here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114263/discussion-between-user3135730-and-tchdvlp).